# Gauss' Eureka Theorem - Number of representations of a positive integer as sum of three triangular numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

**Gauss' Eureka Theorem** states that every positive integer can be represented as the sum of three triangular numbers.

i.e.,

$$
N = \frac{a(a+1)}{2} + \frac{b(b+1)}{2} + \frac{c(c+1)}{2} \tag{1}
$$

What I have so far:

Eqn. $(1)$ is equivalent to

$$
8N + 3 = (2a+1)^2 + (2b+1)^2 + (2c+1)^2 
$$

So, the number of representation of $N$ as three triangular numbers is the same as the number of representations of $8N+3$ as sum of three odd squares. Is that correct?

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to systematically generate these representations of $N$ denoted by $(a,b,c)$?
2. Is there an explicit formula for the number of such representations?

Please let me know if there are sources that I may refer to understand approaches to answer the above.

Comment: The number of representations is given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_function).  Because all squares $\pmod 8$ are $0,1,4$ any representation of $8N+3$ is by three odd squares.

Comment: There's an [OEIS sequence for ordered representations](https://oeis.org/A008443), and [another one](https://oeis.org/A002636) for unordered representations, but there's no nice closed form in either.